# Validate dynamic fields using v-validate field binding

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm validating date in datetime picker using the following code:

```
 <tr v-for="(input,k) in inputs" :key="k">
    <datetime v-validate="validators.ArrivalDate" format="YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s" name="arrivalDateTime" v-model="input.arrivalDateTime" ></datetime> 
 <tr>
```

> script:

```
data(){
return {
validators: {
            ArrivalDate: {
                required: true,
                date_format: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
                after: this.inputs.departureDateTime,
            }
            },
  inputs: [
              {
                name:'',
                arrivalDateTime: '',
                departureDateTime:'',
}]
..
```

i want arrival date time should be greater than `this.inputs.departureDateTime` Departure field date time. Only issue is i want to pass index of fields also to `after:this.inputs.departureDateTime`.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `v-validate` string, containing a dynamic value of `after` for each `v-for` iterator:

```html
<tr v-for="(input,k) in inputs" :key="k">
  <datetime 
    name="departureDateTime"
    v-validate="'date_format:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss|required'"
    v-model="input.departureDateTime"
  >
  </datetime>

  <datetime 
    name="arrivalDateTime"        
    v-validate="`after:${input.departureDateTime}|date_format:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss|required`"
    v-model="input.arrivalDateTime"
  >
  </datetime>
<tr>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-date-time-range-in-veevalidate-gnfmy?file=/src/App.vue)